# Spring Cloud Gateway - Customer filter is not applied

Tags: spring, spring-boot, filter, filtering, spring-cloud-gateway

It's been 2 days now that I'm trying to apply a custom filter by extending AbstractGatewayFilterFactory inside my gateway but it still not working. I don't understand cause I have followed step by step the way to implement a filter described at https://spring.io/blog/2022/08/26/creating-a-custom-spring-cloud-gateway-filter. When I add spring.cloud.gateway.default-filters=AuthFilter inside my application.properties the filter is applied but for all routes but I just want to apply it for specific route.

I have seen many similar topic in stackoverflow but none of them work for me.

I have tried to apply a custome filter inside my gateway by following step by step the way described at https://spring.io/blog/2022/08/26/creating-a-custom-spring-cloud-gateway-filter.

I'm expecting to find a solution for applying my custom filter.

**EDIT :**

I finally solved this problem. For everyone who still got this problem refer to this topic [Problem with Spring cloud gateway filters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73113632/problem-with-spring-cloud-gateway-filters?rq=2)